# Does the two-state gene expression model apply to constitutive genes?

Tags: molecular-biology, gene-expression, transcription

Wikipedia defines constitutive genes as

> a gene that is transcribed continually as opposed to a facultative gene, which is only transcribed when needed.

I don't have a strong theoretical background biology/molecular biology, and I am currently studying gene expression analytically, specifically the two-state model of gene expression, where a gene can be on the 'ON' or 'OFF' state.
From this definition I get the understanding that constitutive genes are always in the 'ON' state, although I am not sure if that is the case since other sources describe constitutive genes as genes that are expressed at a relatively constant level, which could still be a gene fluctuating between 'ON/OFF' states.

Comment: This question cannot be answered as it solely depends on the definition of OFF and ON states. I.e. is it defined by a certain protein-assembly that would attract the RNA-pol? Or does it mean that the genes is currently being transcribed? Does it depend on the DNA-accessibility? I guess your model is NOT biologically defined and instead just wants to fit some data. In this case, this question makes no sense. It's just a model and does not have to be compared to any biological 'reality'. If it fits the data, it's good!

Comment: @KaPy3141I think it very much can be answered, and your comment is the beginning of such an answer.